# Geometry nodes: How do I boolean-union N overlapping instanced objects?

Tags: geometry-nodes, boolean-modifier

I used geometry nodes to point-instance object A to object B.
The resulting instances of A now overlap, which is intended.
For further work it would be nice if the resulting mesh is a clean union instead of an overlapping mess.

In the geometry nodes all the instances of A are represented by 1 line so i dont know how to use a mesh boolean node in there.
And when converting object B to a mesh to apply the geometry nodes the resulting mesh still consists of unconnected instances of A. How do i create a union of the A meshes either during the geometry nodes or after?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the *Mesh Boolean* node and only plug a single *Geometry* into it, no matter which Boolean operation you choose (*Difference*, *Intersect* or *Union*), this mesh will be merged together as if you used a *Union* operation on the separate parts of it, as you can see in *Wireframe* view.

Before using a *Mesh Boolean*:

[image: before boolean operation]

After using a *Mesh Boolean*:

[image: after boolean operation]

I used a *Bevel* modifier afterwards to show the result more clearly, you can see the new edges where the cubes are merged get beveled as well:

[image: beveled new edges]